# Hyperref's Autoref When Using the Same Counter for Theorems, Lemmas, Etc

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, autoref

First, apologies if this is a duplicate: I have genuinely searched for the question, but haven't been able to find it!

I am using the same counter for my theorems, lemmas, propositions, etc. I want to use `\autoref` (or another package) in the following way: upon calling `\autoref{result1}`, I get back `Theorem 1`, but upon calling `\autoref{result2}` I get `Lemma 2`. This probably isn't particularly clear, so I've put in a MWE, using `autoref` and `cleveref`. In both cases, I always get the word 'Theorem' where I want 'Lemma'.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref, cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}     {Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\def\thmautorefname{Theorem}
\def\lemautorefname{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm} \label{T1}  Theorem 1... \end{thm}
\begin{lem} \label{L2}  Lemma 2... \end{lem}

\autoref{T1} \autoref{L2}

\Cref{T1} \Cref{L2}

\end{document}
```

I want the output to be "Theorem 1 Lemma 2", but at the moment it's "Theorem 1 Theorem 2".

Comment: For `cleveref` this works if you use e.g. the `amsthm` package for your theorems.

Comment: If I add the package `amsthm` to the above preamble, then this doesn't solve my issue... would you care to elaborate?

Comment: I have added an example below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment, for `cleveref` the names in `\cref`'s are correct if you use the `amsthm` package:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref,cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}     {Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm} \label{T1}  Theorem 1\dots \end{thm}
\begin{lem} \label{L2}  Lemma 2\dots \end{lem}

\Cref{T1} \Cref{L2}

\end{document}
```

You also get correct names if you use the `thmtools` or the `ntheorem` package instead of `amsthm`.  Even better the `thmtools` package also corrects `hyperref`s `\autoref` command:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{thmtools,hyperref,cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}     {Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm} \label{T1}  Theorem 1\dots \end{thm}
\begin{lem} \label{L2}  Lemma 2\dots \end{lem}

\autoref{T1} \autoref{L2}

\Cref{T1} \Cref{L2}

\end{document}
```

When experimenting remember to compile twice to see the effect of a package change, as a first run of `latex` puts information about these labels in the `.aux` file, which is then read on the second run for use in the referencing commands.

Comment: See, that is confusing, because I'm sure that I'd used `amsthm` before you suggested it, and then again when you suggested it, and neither worked. Yet now I've just tried it on my home computer (instead of office), and it works! \\ I'll try it tomorrow on my office computer, see if there was something I was doing wrong... otherwise this is perfect: Christian's solution took me ages to put in my preamble (needed to do quite a bit for quite a few things -- yours is slicker, I feel... providing I can make it work!)

Comment: You need to make sure you run latex twice so the changes to the `.aux` file on the first run can be used in the second run to generate the references including their names.

Comment: That does indeed work for me. I think maybe I was using only `\autoref` not `cleveref`. I wish I'd seen your commented before implementing Christian's: I had 10 things (lemma, proposition, claim, ...) that I had to put the stuff in for; took ages =P

Answer (score 3):

Using shared counters for the lemma etc. can be tricky -- neither `\cref` nor `\autoref` know which counter is refstepped internally, so both assume `thm` here.

With the package `aliascnt` a name alias for an existing counter can be defined, say `\newaliascnt{lem}{thm}`.

In conjunction with `\newtheorem` `\aliascntresetthe{lem}` must be used.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{hyperref, cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newaliascnt{lem}{thm}
\newtheorem{lem}[lem]{Lemma}
\aliascntresetthe{lem}
\def\thmautorefname{Theorem}
\def\lemautorefname{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm} \label{T1}  Theorem 1... \end{thm}
\begin{lem} \label{L2}  Lemma 2... \end{lem}

\autoref{T1} \autoref{L2}

\Cref{T1} \Cref{L2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you :) -- took quite a while to write all that stuff in, but it's done now!

Comment: Can I ask, is there a way to use a plural version? For example `\Cref{thm1,thm2}` outputs `Theorems 1 and 2`?

Comment: Add `\crefname{lem}{lemma}{lemmas}
\Crefname{Lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}` in order to make the corresponding names available for `cleveref`. I'm unsure about the plural of `lemma` in English. In German, it would be `Lemmata`

Comment: Perfect, thanks :) -- "Lemmas" is fine for English :)

Comment: Thank you, Christian, for your answer, but I've actually accepted Andrew's now. (I hope that's ok!) Your suggestion, while working perfectly, meant adding quite a lot to my preamble: I had 10 things (lemmas, propositions, claims, etc) that I had to add it to. I feel Andrew's is slicker, so I've accepted it, but you *definitely* still get my +1! -- I also like learning more about tex stuff, so yours is helpful for that too!